# Tooltip gets cut off when a table container has overflow-x auto

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have found a lot of issues related to this one, but not one that matches the exact same problem and I was also not able to resolve my problem with other "related" issues. Below you can see two screenshots, one with overflow-x: auto and one without.

**With overflow-x: auto**
[[With overflows-x][]1]

**Without overflow-x: auto**
[[Without overflows-x][]1]

So overflow-x auto is cutting off my tooltip when it overflows vertically. I do not know why it behaves this way, even if I put overflow-y visible on it, it does not work.

**Reason I am using overflow-x: auto**

I am using overflow-x: auto to make my table responsive on resize. This will give me a scrollbar when the content does not fit. I see that many people use this to make their tables responsive.

**Important code parts that I am currently using**

**HTML**

```
       <div key={uniqueKey} className={'table-container'}>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope='col'>Id</th>
                        <th scope='col'>Name</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {someList.map((item, index) => {
                        return (
                            <tr key={index}>
                                <td data-label='Id'>{id}</td>
                                <td data-label='Name'>{name}</td>
                                <td data-label='Actions'>
                                    <div className={'actions-container'}>
                                        // EXISTING TOOLTIP COMPONENT HERE, I WILL SHOW THE CSS.
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        );
                    })}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.table-container {
overflow-x: auto;
border-collapse: separate;
table-layout: fixed;

table {
    width: 100%;

    tr {
        height: 40px;
    }

    td {
        height: auto;
    }

    th {
        min-width: 175px;
        padding: 8px;
    }
}}
```

**CSS Tooltip**

```
.tooltip{
width: 300px;
background-color: black;
color: #fff;
text-align: center;
padding: 5px;
border-radius: 6px;
position: absolute;
z-index: 100;
word-break: normal;
opacity: 0;
visibility: hidden;
transition: opacity 0.5s;
transition-delay: 0.4s;}
```

**Other notes**

- I can not modify the tooltip too much since it is a existing component within our company, we would have to change it on lots of places. Also it works as expected on other places.
- If there is any information missing, just let me know and I will respond as soon as possible.

Any insights are welcome at this point!

Comment: Can you please share the code for the tool tip component?

Answer (score 4):

We had faced similar issue. The way we solved this is add a support to render the tooltip view in a react portal instead.

> You'll need a component change but you don't need to change a lot of existing code.

Add a portal component:

```js
const Portal = (props) => {
    const { children, target = document.body } = props;
    return ReactDOM.createPortal(children, target);
};
```

> Add a `usePortal` prop that'll render the view in portal instead. Otherwise the view will be rendered as it is currently.

You'll have a `viewDom` that renders your tooltip view, use the Portal component:

```js
const { usePortal } = props;
const viewDom = <span> Your view dom </span>;
if (usePortal) {
    return (
        <Portal>
          { viewDom }
        </Portal>
    )
}

// otherwise return the default dom without portal
return viewDom;
```

Comment: Thanks Pritam for the response. A React Portal looks like something that might be a "pretty" solution, I am going to test it as soon as I have time!

Comment: If I try this solution, the positioning and styling of the tooltip gets completely screwed up. Is that behavior that you did expect?

Comment: yes, if you use sass, the tooltip view classes need to be moved outside any container wrapper class or better yet, move them to your root styles file.

Comment: this is because the once you use portals for view, the view will be in a dom outside normal order which will break the styles

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure if this would solve the issue or not, but I noticed that the visibility is set to **hidden** and that will hide everything that doesn’t fit within that specific div.  You might want to try setting that to **visible** to see if it fixes this cut off issue.  I have no idea if that is the fix to this, but I wanted to try and help ha ha.

Comment: Thanks for the response UXOL. The visibility is getting set to Visible in the hover of the component. So the solution is not that easy unfortunate.

Comment: I figured that it wasn’t that simple and web design isn’t my forte ha ha.  I just wanted to see if I could take a stab at it.  Thank you for the response.  Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

If your tooltips have a max-height, you can add padding/margin top to the table to clear that height.

So if

```
.tooltip {
  ...
  max-height: 3em;
}
table {
  margin-top: 3em;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jkuss for the response. This would either require a lot of space OR on hover it would move the table down right? I think that is not what you want with a tooltip, it should overlay.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested it but your `tr` only has 40px height and will cut off the overflow on auto, because your three lines of text will take more than 40px space at all.
You should try to set the `tr` to `position:relative` and the tooltip to `position:absolute` for positioning and forget about the overflow;